# Embedded video, youtube, vimeo, other not working in IE11

Tags: video, internet-explorer-11

So the subject says it all. I've tried a number of video hosting platforms, and neither iframe, embed, object or javascript embeds work.

It's an HTML4.1 site i'm maintaining.

I know this has been asked a LOT. Maybe someone can help.

https://www.parkslopecc.com/defaultvidtest.asp

Of course, it all works Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most possible reason is 'Shockwave Flash Object' add on is not installed or it is disabled in Internet Explorer.

[image]

I had made a test on 2 different machines has IE 11. One has this add on and other does not.

The IE 11 which has this add on playing the videos from Iframe or embedded object fine.

The IE 11 which does not has this add on not playing the videos.

So you can try to have a check on your side and confirm that this add on is installed and enabled.

If this add on is not installed then you can try to install it from link below.

[Adobe Shockwave Player](https://get.adobe.com/shockwave/otherversions/)

Comment: Well thank you Deepak! Hopefully other potential clients have Shockwave installed. I appreciate you clearing this up!